# Fastest way to collect an arbitrary army

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, algorithm

I am looking for solution of this puzzle:

> There is a kingdom with a square shape with sides of length 1. The castle is located at the center of the square. At the castle the king lives under the protection of one soldier. There are other soldiers, but each soldier is at his own house. Houses are spread throughout the area of the kingdom, and everyone is aware of where they are.
>
> A war has been declared with a neighboring kingdom, and the king needs to collect all the soldiers at the castle urgently. To do this, he sends the soldier at the castle with the news to gather troops from the other places. Each soldier who learned the news, if necessary, can participate in the gathering. They can travel at the speed of 1.
>
> What is the minimum time in which the king can collect all solders, **regardless** of their number and initial placement? (Number of soldiers is finite).

I see that the time should satisfy:

> $$T_{min} \geq 2+\sqrt{2} = 3.4142...$$ This is the minimum time to gather solders from 4 houses in square's corners.
>
>  $T = 2+\sqrt{2}$ feels to be the minimum: somehow with help of new solders everyone in a middle zone should be gathered while the very first solder goes via 3 corners.

But I have no idea how to find a generic algorithm for $T_{\mathrm{min}}$, which will achieve such a time for arbitrary number of houses.

P.S. Please be aware when you formulate your algorithm and prove it that there are so many possibilities that it is easy to miss something. I tried many times already, feeling that I've almost got it. But my solutions always had some small unclearness, and when I investigated the "proof" more explicitly and carefully I would find a gap in it...

P.P.S. I tried the following strategy:

1. When solder decides to go to some house he "reserves" it.
2. Once a solder is free (has delivered the news to another house) he takes the closest house from all unreserved and goes there. If there are several closest houses he chooses at random.

[It doesn't work.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/605/does-this-strategy-works)

Comment: Sounds like a binary tree form of space filling curve for a square is needed. If there are 2 soldiers per house, http://msl.cs.uiuc.edu/~lavalle/papers/KufLav11.pdf might work.

Comment: Ah, there's something called the H-tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_tree . It can be used to derive a lower bound of $1+\sqrt{2}$. Your lower bound is better than that.

Comment: @Memming:  Last I checked $2+\sqrt 2 \gt 1+\sqrt 2$  I agree with klm123's assessment of the four corners.  The H tree is shorter, but it assumes there are soldiers at every point.

Comment: Some thoughts: (1) If the soldiers' positions are known, then the time needed depends on those positions, and the question is missing necessary info. So assume the positions aren't known. (2) If each soldier's house is a point, then the curves the seekers take need to meet that point. But a finite-length curve isn't dense in the square. ([Space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) are theoretical only: no soldier can actually walk along such a curve.) So there's no guarantee the seekers will find anyone. So assume soldiers' houses are $x\times x$ units. (Cont'd.)

Comment: Some thoughts, continued: (3) We should assume a house is visible from a distance of, say, $10x$, and that, once a seeker spots a house, he'll go directly to it.

Comment: @msh210, seeker knows all houses and can decide where he goes from very begining.

Comment: @msh210, time needed depends on the positions. But minimum time needed does not.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. More soldiers to recruit can make it faster. If there are infinite number of soldiers on the boundary of the kingdom and no where else, how long does it take? It takes 3/2!

Comment: @Memming  It takes about $2\sqrt 2$.  The first soldier goes to one corner, sends the one at the corner to one nearby. Very soon, somebody travels the diagonal to get the soldier in the opposite corner, who goes straight home.

Comment: @RossMillikan For this special case, it takes 1+\sqrt{5}/2 if the first soldier goes to the closest soldier and spreads to the entire kingdom from that point. (my initial answer was wrong.)

Comment: I think the generic algorithm can be written from the pairwise distance matrix.

Comment: Note that finding a general strategy short of checking every possible path is probably hopeless as this look extremely similar to the travelling salesman problem which is NP-complete.

Comment: Does the King help?

Comment: @ballesta25: often only a small modification to a problem can make it much easier. Moreover, checking each possible path is not viable, since there aren't a finite number of situations to deal with.

Answer (score 7):

I have the following results that lead some of the way towards an answer:

1. If a knight starts at the middle of a square of sidelength $a$ then he can collect all the knights in that square and bring them to its centre in time at most $Ca$, for some constant $C$ not depending on $a$ or the number of knights. (This proves that we can't slow down the first knight for ages just by putting loads of knights closely surrounding the castle.)
2. For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$, $n$ knights can always be collected from the kingdom in time $2\sqrt{2}+\varepsilon$. (If we put the knights in two opposite corners it will take at least time $2\sqrt{2}$. So we can see that for large numbers of knights the time needed tends to $2\sqrt 2$.)
3. There exists some $p$ and some arrangement of $p$ knights such that collecting the knights from that arrangement takes at least as long as collecting any number of knights from any other arrangement. (So the problem actually has an answer!)
4. The times needed for small numbers of knights are:

   - 1 knight: $0$
   - 2 knights: $\sqrt 2$
   - 3 knights: $2\sqrt 2$
   - 4 knights: $2\sqrt 2$
   - 5 knights: $2+\sqrt 2$
5. Collecting $6$ knights (including the first one from the castle) can always be done in time $\frac{1}{2}+2\sqrt 2$, which is less than $2+\sqrt 2$, the time needed to collect $5$ knights.

I'll give the proofs when I get round to writing them up. (Hints: 1. splits the square into 4 and uses recursion, 2. splits the square into $k^2$ small squares and uses the pigeonhole principle to find a small square with enough knights that each one can be sent to each of the other squares, 3. uses 2 to produce an upper bound on $p$ and then uses a compactness argument to show that the bound is achieved, 4. just involves looking at each case in detail, and 5. splits the square into 4 and starts at the quarter with 2 knights in it)

Comment: Looking forward to the completion of this answer!

Answer (score 6):

I've already shown how you can force my other answer to fail.  Hopefully this one will not have such an exploit.

- Step 1: First knight goes to the extreme house on the map.
  (Equivalent to just going the the north house if there is a house
  there.) (Maximum time $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)  For a sometimes faster
  but harder to visualize strategy, instead have him go to the closest house and
  divide the entire map by the line along which he just travelled.
- Step 2: Old knight updates his map by drawing two lines to the houses
  on his left and right with a minimal angle between the such that all
  other houses on his map are between these lines.  He then divides this map
  into two halves by bisecting this angle.

  Step 3: The old knight and the new knight proceed to the closest
  houses that is on their halves of the map.

  Step 4: Each knight follows steps 2 and 3 until he is awarded a map
  with no houses on it (and as a result no area). (Maximum time $2$)

  Step 5: Knight proceeds back to the castle. (Maximum time
  $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)

A potentially simpler to state step 2 would be to merely divide the current map into two equal halves along a line which passes through the current location. Unfortunately, already emptied space would remain on one of these maps making them less useful.

Step 2 is easier than is sounds as it is usually trimming an emptied triangle off a triangle then bisecting the new triangle.

This seems to work for every answer so far.  One can imagine on map getting repeatedly divided into halves until nothing remains.  It is area filling so it resolves any issues from house bunches (More at [Does this strategy work?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/605/does-this-strategy-work/607?noredirect=1#comment1497_607)). No knight can be eliminated without removing at least one house and significantly reducing the number of houses. (what killed my other answer).

So far I've been completely unable to create a counter example or a proof.  I welcome any input.

[image]

This (rather rough) diagram shows several moves of steps 2 and 3 for a random pattern of houses.  the original map is bounded by black.  They second map pink.  This continues through green and blue.  The houses are red and the path traveled is purple.  Original location is black.

Comment: What is "left" and "right" of a knight? I'm thinking of some positioning, which will leave The angle always > 90, but I can't fully understand the formal procedure to proceed with my examples..

Comment: I mean you draw the minimum angle which would encompase all houses. This angle could extend behind the house and be greater than 180 if you can come up with a good one for that.

Comment: so the knight takes responsibility for an area and all houses in it. each time he draws two closest lines (one would be called left, one is right, but this doesn't matter), which limit all "his" houses?

Comment: "his houses" are the ones that are on his current map.  He is trimming the map down to remove the area that does not have any houses on it before he cuts it in half for the the house seeking trip.  I'll drawn an example.

Comment: Why is 2 the maximum time in step 4?

Comment: Because I am aware that there is a map that yields 2 for that step. I believe that is the maximum for several reasons but am not statisfied with my ability to prove it. If you can prove that statement, you prove that the maximum time for any arbitrary map is $2+\sqrt {2} $.

Comment: If I understood it correctly it's a nice idea but it doesn't work: take a spiral that start in A and put points on it very close one to the other. At each new point one knight give up and the other follow the spiral leading to a length of more than $2 + \sqrt(2)$

Comment: @Ara I'm not convinced I'm wrong; I probably miscommunicated.  Unless there is only one house left on a a map, there is no reason one knight would give up and one would continue. How do you think you can design the field such that one knight quits every time?  No matter what each knights map at least halves in size at least each time he hits a house which is the crux of the idea. I'm not saying your wrong but I'd like to know more.

Comment: If I have a spiral like that: http://imgur.com/cpB9fYe
Then locally it looks like this: http://imgur.com/HdNQ6C8
If it's the case then I feel like you'll go around much of the spiral, which can be arbitrary long. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @Ara The first house right after the castle will cause there to be 2 knights.  The map will be cut in half along a line that goes though the first house and (roughly) the center of the spiral. One knight will recieve the bottom half of that map and will go to the next point along the spiral. The other knight will get the top half and go to the closest point to him on that map.  No knight will end up following a path that looks like a spiral though several will follow one that goes along a curve.

Comment: @Ara I think from the local one you think they cut the entire map in half based along their last path?  They trim the map carried by the knight who went to their current location so no knight gets an empty map.  They then bisect that map into equal area sections.  **Each half by this method always has at least one house on it** (unless there is 1 house or 0 houses on both halves of the map total).

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. I'll try to see If I can come up with a proof than your strategy work in finite time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm that doesn't always work (see a counter-example at the end). A slight adjustment (if a knight has no houses in his region he can take a portion of the other knight at his house's region) seems like it would fix this but it is not in this answer.

Step 1: Determine the lower bound:
If the knights are located at the 4 corners it will take: $\sqrt{(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2}+1+1+\sqrt{(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2} = 2+\sqrt{2}$.
The first one goes to a corner, he and the corner liver goes to the other two closest corner, someone of those 4 go to the last corner, and then everyone goes to the center.

Step 2: Show the lower bound works for any pattern:
Assume that there is a knight in a corner as this is the furthest point away from the king.  If no one is further than that it should make the solution faster but more complicated. Use the following strategy as it is easier to show but slowest. For this algorithm one knight goes to a corner, they progress to the other corner and when everyone is notified, go to the castle.  If every house is reached within 2 time after the first house is reached, they can all get back as they are at most $\sqrt{1/2}$ away.

Send the first knight to a corner call the corner in this direction North (N) for simplicity. You will then have two knights.  Have them go to houses by this algorithm:

The knight divide the map into two regions by the East/West location of their current house. One knight goes to the northmost house which has not been visited, no other knight is headed towards, and is to the East of the current location. If multiple houses are the same distance north, he goes to the closer one. If there are no houses to the East he should go to the castle.  The other knight follows the same algorithm but to the West.  If there is a house directly South, it can count as either East or West but don't send both to the same house!.

Each time you visit a house, repeat the same algorithm with the two knights then at the house except no knight may move into a region which was excluded by one of his predecessors.

As no knight goes north again (until they are going to the castle) and the knights are interchangeable, the shortest path connecting the north and south corner houses via this algorithm will be taken.  The maximum distance for this shortest path is $2$.  This is because there is at least one path taken by which $\Delta S \ge |\Delta E|$ for every trip between houses.  Similarly paths will go to the East most and West most houses that will never go in the other direction and, therefore, will have a path length of at most $2$.

There are likely faster algorithms than this for a particular setup but this one goes to all within the lower bound.  Essentially each knight will take his map, draw two vertical lines based on his location and the history of his messenger, and go to the closest northmost house in his region.  As the regions get smaller, they can be filled faster.

[image]

In the example above (which only shows the house covering part of the algorithm), purple is the paths knights take, blue the region dividers, and red the houses.  If the houses not at the corners are $0.05$ from the corners and $22.5^\circ$ degrees from the edge, it takes $1.42$ units of time to go from N to S and $1.004$ units to get to either other corner.

[image]

This second example does not work by this algorithm. If the house near the south corner is slightly to the west of the house near the center (labeled). The limit of the time to complete this algorithm as d goes to zero is: $2\sqrt{.5}+1 \approx 2.4$. Several other knights are available to get to that last house before the knight that does but is not defined in the algorithm.

Comment: I think this works as a hint/algorithm but I'm having difficultly with a formal proof.

Comment: I've not completely sorted out what you wrote yet. But I understand you send very first knight to very corner. Are you sure that the algorithm will work for situation with 8 houses, 4 right in corners and 4 near them, let's say 0.05 distance from corners, but not on the edge or diagonal?

Comment: The point of this algorithm is to show that they will go to the extreme corners covering every house within 2 units of time.  Would the angle halfway between the diagonal and all clockwise work for a demonstration?

Comment: The most simple explanation: Each time a knight reaches a new house, he splits his region into two halves vertically (note I am visualizing this as a square diamond), keeps half for himself and gives half to the new knight, and both go to the northmost house in their region.

Comment: Yes. You draw the example I meant. But the paths looks very odd to me. Why on the picture the start is at S? The start point is the centre and they all should go back to the center afterwards.

Comment: The start for this diagram is at North! I did not include them going to the center nor from the center as that would clutter the diagram.  The essensce of this answer is to go from the extreme corner in less that 2, get to their starting point in $\sqrt {.5}$ (trivial), and back to the castle in $\sqrt {.5}$ (again trivial).

Comment: Upon rereading it I realise I may not have been clear that my goal was to determine an algorithm by which any finite map of houses could be reached within the lower bound for the minimum time that is defined in Step 1.

Comment: I understand the picture now. Thank you. The algorithm I understand too, I hope. But the prove is not clear to me. Why "the shortest path connecting the north and south corner houses via this algorithm will be taken. The maximum distance for this shortest path is 2."? There can be many houses on the path to south.

Comment: Also it is not clear what to do if there no house in the very North (in the corner). Then distance to East can be longer. But  this is a good hint in any case, so I give it +1.

Comment: I've found a way this algorithm does not work but it was because of my attempts to simplify it after I had already written the answer. I had orginally had knights attempt to use diagonal region cuts rather than vertical ones. If there is no house at the North most corner, use a corner that has a house. If no corner has a house, use the furthest point away from the castle.  I've not tested this.

Comment: $2\sqrt{.5}=2\sqrt{1/2}=2/\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Taemyr I am aware of that; do I get something wrong pertaining to that somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

*(Note: This answer is a work in progress. See [relevant meta discussion](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1283/1622) if you would rather answers such as this did not exist.)*

I don't like complicated things so I immediately chose to solve some simple variants of this problem before scaling up to the full deal. The simplest variant adds these assumptions:

1. No more than one house can occupy the same place
2. All houses are located on a straight line
3. The castle is located on the "end" of the line
4. There is no size restriction for the kingdom

This is a trivial variant of the problem and the solution is to send the original solider along the line until it reaches the last house on the line. Every other solider immediately returns to the castle. The time taken will be $t = 2x$ where $x$ is the distance between the castle and the house farthest away.

---

The next variant follows these assumptions instead:

1. No more than one house can occupy the same place
2. All houses are located on a straight line
3. **The castle can be located anywhere on the line**
4. There is no size restriction for the kingdom

To start digging for patterns, I used the following example (`X` is the castle; other letters are houses):

```
A---B-X--C
```

The optimal strategy will always be:

- Send Solider 1 ($SX$) to $B$, generating Solider 2 ($SB$)
- Send $SX$ to $A$, send $SB$ to $C$
- Send all soldiers home

The cost for this will be:

- $\overline{BX} + \max(\overline{AB}+\overline{AB}+\overline{BX}, \overline{BX}+\overline{CX}+\overline{CX})$
- $= \overline{BX} + \max(2*\overline{AB}+\overline{BX}, \overline{BX}+2*\overline{CX})$
- $= 2*\overline{BX} + \max(2*\overline{AB}+\overline{BX}, \overline{BX}+2*\overline{CX})$
- $= 2*(\overline{BX} + \max(\overline{AB}, \overline{CX}))$

The second example for this variant is:

```
A---B-X--C--D
```

The optimal strategy is no longer static and requires knowledge about the distance between the various houses. Specifically, there are two potential options.

OPTION 1

- $S_X$ to $B$
- $S_X$ to $A$, $S_B$ to $C$
- $S_X$, $S_A$, $S_C$ to X, $S_B$ to $D$
- Send all soldiers home

OPTION 2

- $S_X$ to $C$
- $S_X$ to $D$, $S_C$ to $B$
- $S_X$, $S_D$, $S_B$ to X, $S_C$ to $A$
- Send all soldiers home

Therefore, the optimal time will be:

$\min(\overline{XB}+\max(2*\overline{AB}+\overline{XB},\overline{XB}+2*\overline{XC}+2*\overline{CD}), \overline{XC}+\max(2*\overline{CD}+\overline{XC},\overline{XC}+2*\overline{XB}+2*\overline{AB}))$

```
$= \min(\max(2*\overline{AB}+2*\overline{XB},2*\overline{XB}+2*\overline{XC}+2*\overline{CD}), \max(2*\overline{CD}+2*\overline{XC},2*\overline{XC}+2*\overline{XB}+2*\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*\min(\max(\overline{AB}+\overline{XB},\overline{XB}+\overline{XC}+\overline{CD}), \max(\overline{CD}+\overline{XC},\overline{XC}+\overline{XB}+\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*\min(-\min(-\overline{AB}-\overline{XB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD}), -\min(-\overline{CD}-\overline{XC},-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*(\min(\min(-\overline{CD}-\overline{XC},-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB}), \min(-\overline{AB}-\overline{XB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD}))-\min(-\overline{AB}-\overline{XB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD})-\min(-\overline{CD}-\overline{XC},-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*(\min(-\overline{CD}-\overline{XC},-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB}, -\overline{AB}-\overline{XB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD})-\min(-\overline{AB}-\overline{XB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD})-\min(-\overline{CD}-\overline{XC},-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*(\min(-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD})-\min(-\overline{AB}-\overline{XB},-\overline{XB}-\overline{XC}-\overline{CD})-\min(-\overline{CD}-\overline{XC},-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*(-\max(\overline{XC}+\overline{XB}+\overline{AB},\overline{XB}+\overline{XC}+\overline{CD})+\max(\overline{AB}+\overline{XB},\overline{XB}+\overline{XC}+\overline{CD})+\max(\overline{CD}+\overline{XC},\overline{XC}+\overline{XB}+\overline{AB}))$
$= 2*(\overline{XB}+\overline{XC}+\max(\overline{AB},\overline{XC}+\overline{CD})+\max(\overline{CD},\overline{XB}+\overline{AB})-\overline{XC}-\overline{XB}-\max(\overline{AB},\overline{CD}))$
```

$= 2*(\max(\overline{AB},\overline{XC}+\overline{CD})+\max(\overline{CD},\overline{XB}+\overline{AB})-\max(\overline{AB},\overline{CD}))$

Using some quick numbers:

$\overline{AB}=3, \overline{BX}=1, \overline{XC}=2, \overline{CD}=2$ then:

- $t=2*(\max(3,2+2)+\max(2,1+3)-\max(3,2))$
- $t=2*(4+4-3)=2*5=10$

Presumably this pattern can be extended to apply to *all* scenarios where the houses fit on a line. The second example for this variant is:

```
A---B-X--C--D---E
```

Similarly to the second example, we really only have two potential options:

OPTION 1

- $S_X$ to $B$
- $S_X$ to $A$, $S_B$ to $C$
- $S_X$, $S_A$, $S_C$ to X, $S_B$ to $D$
- $S_B$ to $E$
- Send all soldiers home

OPTION 2

- $S_X$ to $C$
- $S_X$ to $D$, $S_C$ to $B$
- $S_D$, $S_B$ to X, $S_X$ to $E$, $S_C$ to $A$
- Send all soldiers home

$t = \min(\overline{XB}+\max(\overline{XB}+2*\overline{AB},\overline{XB}+2*\overline{XC}+2*\overline{CD}+2*DE), \overline{XC}+\max(\overline{XC}+2*\overline{CD}+2*DE,\overline{XC}+2*\overline{XB}+2*\overline{AB}))$

If we treat $2*\overline{CD}+2*DE$ as $2*CE$ we get this form:

$t = \min(\overline{XB}+\max(\overline{XB}+2*\overline{AB},\overline{XB}+2*\overline{XC}+2*CE), \overline{XC}+\max(\overline{XC}+2*CE,\overline{XC}+2*\overline{XB}+2*\overline{AB}))$

Which matches our previous formula letting us jump to the reduced form:

$= 2*(\max(\overline{AB},\overline{XC}+CE)+\max(CE,\overline{XB}+\overline{AB})-\max(\overline{AB},CE))$
$= 2*(\max(\overline{AB},\overline{XC}+\overline{CD}+CE)+\max(\overline{CD}+CE,\overline{XB}+\overline{AB})-\max(\overline{AB},\overline{CD}+CE))$

At this point, one pattern does reveal itself. The only lines that *really* matter are $XA = \overline{XB}+\overline{AB}$, $XE = \overline{XC}+\overline{CD}+DE$, $\overline{XB}$ and $\overline{XC}$:

$= 2*(\max(\overline{AB},XE)+\max(\overline{CD}+CE,XA)-\max(\overline{AB},\overline{CD}+CE))$
$= 2*(\max(XA-\overline{XB},XE)+\max(XE-\overline{XC},XA)-\max(XA-\overline{XB},XE-\overline{XC}))$

This form seems likely to apply to all scenarios where the houses fit on a line. If we redefine the points in our example:

```
A1---A0-X--B0--B1---B2
```

We can write the formula as:

$= 2*(\max(XA-XA_0,\overline{XB})+\max(\overline{XB}-\overline{XB}_0,XA)-\max(XA-XA_0,\overline{XB}-\overline{XB}_0))$ where $XA=XA_0+A_0A_1+A_1A_2...$ and $\overline{XB}=\overline{XB}_0+B_0B_1+B_1B_2...$

This solution makes intuitive sense. The only real choice in a lined scenario is which direction to go first. Everything after that presents us with the trivial problem noted at the beginning of this post. The primary reason this formula works, however, is because we know that each $XA_0 ... XA_N$ is less than $B_0A_0 ... B_0A_N$ since any solider travelling from $B_0$ to $A_0$ has to pass through $X$. Therefore, this formula is only true if and only if $X$ perfectly splits two sections of the kingdom such that $X$ is always closer to each house in section $A$ compared to each house in section $B$ **and** the houses in each section form a line.

This last clause seems like a good place to extend our approach.

---

The next variant follows these assumptions instead:

1. No more than one house can occupy the same place
2. **All houses exist in either section A or section B such that there is no line between a house in section A and a house in section B that is shorter than travelling from that house to the castle**
3. **All house in a given section $S$ follow the rule that $S_N$ is closer to $S_{N-1}$ and $S_{N+1}$ than any other houses or the castle *unless* the house is $S_0$**
4. The castle can be located anywhere on the line
5. There is no size restriction for the kingdom

This set of assumptions removes the restriction that all houses exist on a line. It should make the math significantly more complicated but let's work it through.

```
A1   A0
           X   B0
```

This example moves $A_0$ and $A_1$ off of a line but preserves Assumption 3 which states that $A_1$ cannot be closer to $X$ than $A_0$. Let's see how this affects the math. The strategy is still the same:

- Send $S_X$ to $A_0$
- Send $S_X$ to $A_1$, send $SA_0$ to $S_{B_0}$
- Send all soldiers home

The two major differences are that $\overline{A_1X}$ no longer passes through $A_0$ and $\overline{A_0B_0}$ no longer passes through $X$. Here is our new formula:

- $\overline{XA_0} + \max(\overline{A_0A_1}+\overline{XA_1}, \overline{A_0B_0}+\overline{XB_0})$

Sadly, we don't get to reduce this at all since we don't get to replace $\overline{A_0B_0}$ with $\overline{XA_0} + \overline{XB_0}$. Let's extend section $A$ again and see what happens:

```
   A1   A0
              X   B0
A2
```

Is the optimal strategy still the same?

- Send $S_X$ to $A_0$
- Send $S_X$ to $A_1$, send $S_{A_0}$ to $B_0$
- Send $S_X$ to $A_2$, send $S_{A_0}$, $S_{A_1}$, $S_{B_0}$ home
- Send all soldiers home

I can see two alternative strategies and it may be tricky to determine if there is a case where one of those strategies outperforms this one. To make this easier to understand, I'll start using the notation $S_X \to A_0 \to A_1 \to A_2 \to X$ to describe one soldier's entire cycle. The above strategy expressed this way:

OPTION 1

- $S_X \to A_0 \to A_1 \to A_2 \to X$
- $S_{A_0} \to {B_0} \to X$
- $S_{A_1} \to X$
- $S_{A_2} \to X$
- $S_{B_0} \to X$

OPTION 2

- $S_X \to A_0 \to A_2 \to A_1 \to X$
- $S_{A_0} \to {B_0} \to X$
- $S_{A_1} \to X$
- $S_{A_2} \to X$
- $S_{B_0} \to X$

OPTION 3

- $S_X \to A_1 \to A_2 \to X$
- $S_{A_1} \to A_0 \to B_0 \to X$
- $S_{A_0} \to X$
- $S_{A_2} \to X$
- $S_{B_0} \to X$

How do we confirm that OPTIONS 2 & 3 are suboptimal for all positions of $A_0...A_N$?

Comment: I apologize for the formatting. I am not terribly experienced with the math formatting yet and don't know the best way to show steps in formula reduction.

Comment: +1 because this is an interesting approach to the problem. But please note that garantee-time is asked, not the most optimal algorithm for given kingdom.

Comment: @klm123: Yes, true. My thinking is that I can find the time it would take for any given algorithm within a particular set of kingdom constraints which would then give me a way to determine the worst case scenario for a given set of kingdom constraints. But I'm a long way off, yet, and don't know if I'll ever get there. In the meantime, maybe it will help someone else figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest method of message passing is usually broadcast - e.g. blowing a horn (or a relay of horns). All soldiers proceed to the castle simultaneously, so the last soldiers to arrive would be ones at the corners, which happens in time $\sqrt{0.5^2 + 0.5^2} = \sqrt{0.5}$.

If the king's soldier must notify everyone in person or by proxy (via other soldiers), then it depends on the distribution of houses.

Suppose the houses are arranged in expanding concentric squares around the castle, with the nearest a negligible distance away. Then the king's soldier goes first to the nearest 'ring' of houses, they go together to notify the next ring and so on, then return. In other words, the wave of soldiers moves out from the castle to the perimeter and then returns to the middle.

The longest path is from the castle to each corner of the square. To get there and back takes $2\sqrt{0.5}$ time. Everyone else travels a shorter distance, so this is also the total muster time.

Other search patterns will be needed if the distribution is sparse. The worst case might be 5 soldiers, 1 at the castle and the other 4 at the corners of the square. The king's soldier travels to 3 of them in turn, sending the first to notify the remaining soldier. This traverses the entire diagonal and 2 sides for the longest path time-wise, taking $2 + \sqrt{2}$ time. I suspect (but am prepared to stand corrected) that in all other cases, some soldiers can be recruited to reduce the total muster time.

Comment: Indeed. The king who hasn't cooked up broadcast deserves to not be king.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an algorithm to find minimal time for a specific kingdom.

1. We need to start by creating a table/map/lookup etc. of distances between every single pair of knights' houses.
2. We then need to generate all the permutations of the ways that the "news" can spread. i.e. Knight0 can go first to Knight1, but could also start by going to Knight2 etc.

   For the Knight at each extreme point example mentioned in the question, I used the notation 0(1(4),2(),3()) to mean:

   - Knight0 travelled to Knight1's house ($\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)
   - Knight0 then travelled to Knight2's house ($1$)
   - Knight0 then travelled to Knight3's house ($1$)
   - Knight0 then travelled back to the castle ($\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)

   Meanwhile, after Knight0 had travelled to Knight1's house,

   - Knight1 then travelled to Knight4's house ($1$)
   - Knight1 then travelled back to the castle ($\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)
3. Once we have every possibility (336 for the above example), we need to calculate the time taken for each of those possibilities.

   For the above example, this would be the distance travelled by Knight0

   $$=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+1+1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = 2 + \sqrt{2}$$
4. Once we have all the times of all the possibilities, we can then pick out the smallest time. (There is always more than one answer, as there is always a choice between two knights as to who visits the final knight before returning to the castle.)

I have written this algorithm in C#. It doesn't take a long time to run, but it cannot handle more than 6 Knights in a kingdom at the moment due to memory problems, but am working on that.

Using the algorithm, $2 + \sqrt{2}$ (or 3.414...) was output as the shortest distance in the above example. So far, randomly generating house positions for 6 Knights has produced no higher values.

Comment: Of course considering all possibilities and choosing the best one will give minimal time for given kingdom. The question is to **find the time value** and prove that it is achievable (presenting the algorithm and proving that it works within this time for **any** kingdom). You do not show any time results, so this answer achieves nothing with respect to the given problem, sorry.

Comment: Could you please post the algorithm at least? I know C++.

Comment: @klm123 Thanks for your feedback. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question. The same minimum cannot apply to all possible numbers of knights. If there was only one other knight to pass the news to and that knight lived negligibly close, the time taken would be negligible. I could understand if you were asking for the the **maximum** time value. As number of knights increases from 1, time taken will increase, but after a certain time, I believe this will decrease again (imagine how fast the news would travel if knights were shoulder to shoulder across the whole area).

Comment: The minimum time is parameter of (or "is applied to", if you prefer) the algorithm, which must be applied to all possible kingdoms.

Comment: @kaine Do you mean the part of the algorithm for creating the permutations (336 in above example) (as this was the most complicated part)? The code is OO so not very postable, but I can add a flow chart once I've figured out how to host an image somewhere.

Comment: @klm123 So you are not after a specific value that is the same for all kingdoms? Just a way of working it out when you know the specifics of the kingdom (i.e. where everyone lives)?

Comment: I don't understand your question... I am for one specific value, I have explained which one.

Comment: So how does that work when there is just one other knight in your army who lives next door? Say it's 0.1 length away. It takes you 0.2 time to gather your army. Already much smaller than the 2+√2 value from your original question.

Comment: @Ali, please read the question, it is about All possible kingdoms. The algorithm must work (give time less or equal to $T_{min}$) for All of them. What you are asking about this question doesn't make any sense for me, sorry I can't understand what you do not understand, everyone else understood this moment correctly right after reading the question.

Comment: @klm123 I'm sorry you are having trouble understanding me. I am just saying it is impossible to have a minimum value that applies to all kingdoms when there will always be at least one kingdom to which it does not hold true.

Comment: @Ali, ok. you need to find maxmin value here.

Comment: I have always had problem understanding this kind of question, just like @All, haha. Yes, the question is asking for "Find the maximum time required over all kingdom possibilities", which is phrased to use the word "minimum" in the original formulation as: "What is the minimum time that the king needs to wait in order to be sure that every soldier will have already been gathered, regardless of the kingdom structure?". It's originally formulated as such to encourage algorithm that finds the "minimax" time, that is, the minimum (based of algo) of the maximum time (based on kingdom layout).

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for explaining @justhalf!

Comment: Permutate is a real word.  It's use in this context seems wrong, I would use generate instead.

Comment: Have added another question that might help break down the problem: [Robots](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/how-long-is-needed-to-clear-the-area-of-robots)

Answer (score -2):

It could be `~1.707` if the King helps.

```
s4 ----- s1 --+
 |       |    |
 |       |    |
 |   K   |    1
 |       |    |
 |       |    |
s3-------s2 --+

 |       |
 +---1---+

 Route taken
 K  -> S1 -> C  => 2 * SQR(((1/2)^2)+((1/2)^2))
 S0 -> S3 -> C  => 2 * SQR(((1/2)^2)+((1/2)^2)) (Aka the Soldier at the castle.)
 S1 -> S2 -> C  => 1 + SQR(((1/2)^2)+((1/2)^2))
 S2 -> C        =>     SQR(((1/2)^2)+((1/2)^2))
 S3 -> S4 -> C  => 1 + SQR(((1/2)^2)+((1/2)^2))
 S4 -> C        =>     SQR(((1/2)^2)+((1/2)^2))
```

Think about it this way the King and S0 take half of the list of house.
   King:= S1, S2
     S0:= S3, S4
When they get to the first house.
They cross that house of the list and first divide the list.
If there is only one house on the list, the soldier who house it is go and fetches them, whilst the solider who originally brought the list heads back.

If there is only 1 additional soldier then the answer is `2 x Distance To Solider` Eg There and back.

Comment: King doesn't help and I do not see how your answer proves that the time is always <= 1.707 if kings helps.

Comment: @kim123 The King and S0 are going to opposite corner simultaneously / concurrently. S1 & S3 are concurrent heading towards S2 & S4, whilst S0 & K are concurrently heading back to the castle. (s3&S4) (S1&S2) then head back to castle at the same time.

Comment: If S1 and S3 are knights then you can't be sure they are at corners, corners can be uninhabited.

Comment: @klm123 The location of the houses are known. It stated that in the question. **Houses are spread throughout the area of the kingdom, and everyone is aware of where they are**

Comment: Are know to you? How? They are know to the king, which decides where to send the knights.

Comment: @kim123 Read what it states  **everyone is aware of where they are**

Comment: Dang it! Everyone knows where the houses are except for us... The problem would be much easier if we did!

Comment: -1. Firstly, it's not said that the king helps. Secondly, it is true that everyone knows the location of every other house, but it doesn't imply that there should be a house at each corner. Thirdly, your answer doesn't extend to more houses. Fourthly, your explanation yields the answer $\sqrt{0.5}+1+\sqrt{0.5} = 2.41$, not 1.71.